# Can you upload a neo4j grass-file via the API

Tags: api, neo4j, grass

Can you upload a neo4j grass-file directly via neo4j's REST API?

I don't want to save the grass-file in an intermediary location and then execute a "style: http://xyz" cypher query - which is cumbersome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but

1. You can drag-and-drop the custom grass file into the Favorites tab of the Neo4j Browser
2. You can set the **browser.post_connect_cmd** option in neo4j.conf to set a style when the browser is connected.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom